# An elementary proof that $B(n)$ grows faster than $k^n$?

Tags: combinatorics

Take $B(n)$ to be the $n$-th Bell number (the number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ into non-empty subsets).

Is there an easy proof that $B(n)$ grows faster than any exponential function of the form $k^n$ (for constant $k$)? Absent that, I'll accept any relatively self-contained proof.

For context: this is a claim made at one step of a solution in the Solutions Manual for Bóna's "A Walk Through Combinatorics", but no proof of this step is provided.

Comment: is $k$ a fixed number ? If so, you can use the recursion representation of bell number to show $B_n$ actually grows at least with factorial speed. $B_{n+1} = \sum C_n^k B_k \ge B_n + n B_{n-1}$

Comment: Break up set pf $2n$ elements into two parts. Then roughly speaking $B(2n)\ge B(n)B(n)+n^2 B(n-2)$ where you might have a slower growing function that $n^2$ but still $\to\infty$. (sub-)Exponential function can't satisfy this recurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the set of size $n$ is just the numbers from $1$ to $n$ and now let's construct a large amount of set partitions. First take $1,2,3,\dots, \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and put them each in their own set. Now for the remaining $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ elements we can add them to the existing sets in all possible ways giving $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil ^ {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}$ set partitions of this form, which is larger than $k^n$ once $n$ is larger than roughly $2k^2$.

Comment: That's a great elementary argument, thanks. I do think that you end up with a slightly more elegant bounding step if you use $\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor^{\left\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rceil}$ instead; that gets bounded below by $\left(\sqrt{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\right)^n$, which is larger than $k^n$ exactly when $n>2k^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most direct proof is to show the following formula: (for example, via the exponential generating function) $$B_n = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j^n}{j!} $$

In particular, this shows that $B_n$ grows faster than $\frac{1}{\lceil k+1\rceil!e}\lceil k+1\rceil^n$, which grows faster than $k^n$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I admit I was looking for a way that avoided generating functions; this problem precedes that topic in the textbook, and so I wouldn't expect readers to make use of that result. Is there a nice way to prove that formula without going that route?

Comment: @EricAstor There is an explanation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula) on how to derive this formula by computing the $n$-th moment of a Poisson distribution.  It's also possible to show this formula using induction and the recurrence relation (though this still has the flavor of generating functions).